# Communicating between React Components to conditionally render component

Tags: reactjs

i have a react project whose setup is like

```
<Navbar/> //A components which contains a hamburger menu which on clicking should open sidebar from left side

<Sidebar/> //the component which opens from left side when hamburger icon from <Navbar/> component is clicked
```

So both my components are then called and store in another

Header.js

which contains code as

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Navbar/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./Sidedrawer/Sidedrawer";
export default function Index() {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Navbar/>
      <Sidebar />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

so how do i somehow on clicking hamburger icon in Navbar.js toggle state in Header.js so that i can conditionally render ""Sidebar"" component ?
I am getting confuse to make components communicate with each other cause its not parent - child relationship where i could use callback and all

Navbar.js

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <i className="fas fa-bars"/> //This on clicking should somehow change state on header.js or here and then send updated state to the file in order to conditionally render Sidebar Component
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: You could use some global state management tool to keep the 'open' state. Redux and MobX are popular libraries for this.

Comment: The React [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) can be used as a light-weight state-management system as well if you don't want to go for the full-blown app state management solution of redux/mobx (Hint: react-redux is an abstraction using react contexts). These all utilize a [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) pattern, storing the "common" state in a "common" ancestor component, in these cases, some provider component.

Comment: okay got it well using both react-redux and context in same project isnt a drawback i guess ?

Comment: Nope, not all all. I work with an app that uses react-redux, so there is a redux provider, react-intl for localization, a theme provider, a fair amount of material-ui components that maintain their own internal contexts (i.e. tabs and tab groups), react-router-dom which has its own context, etc, etc...